# How to check if a function is an async function from within a class

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following snippet of code:

```
import asyncio

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(self.func2))
        # The following block of code does not identify func2 as an async function
        for i in dir(self):
            if not i.startswith('__'):  # To eliminate inclusion of dunder functions
                print(i, asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(i))

    def func1(self):
        pass

    async def func2(self):
        pass


Test()
```

When I try to check if a function is an async function using the class name attached to the function name, it works as expected and returns `False` for func1 `True` for func2 which is expected.

But when I try to do the same without using the class name attched to the function (see the code in the for block) by using dir() on self and loop through each function one by one and check if they are async or not, it does not work as expected and returns `False` for `func1` which is expected but also for `func2` not expected and wrong.

Results:

```
True
func1 False
func2 False
```

Tl;dr:
How can I loop through every function available in a class and check if they are async or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir()` returns a list of the names of the methods, essentially a list of strings.

To get the actual methods, you can use the [`inspect.getmembers()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) function.
Your loop should look like this:

```
for name, method in inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
    if not name.startswith('__'):  # To eliminate inclusion of dunder functions
        print(name, asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(method))
```